# CSS Responsive Images either max-width or max-height

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently working on my very first responsive webdesign working with Bootstrap 3.

What I now have is a full-width grid of user profile images. These images have a parent container which must be fully filled by the image. The parent container must have a fixed height because of the requested layout.

The problem is: Using CSS I only know how to fit either the width or the height, not depending on the size of the container.

You can see the problem in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/usD2d/

```
li /* container */ {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px; /* something fixed */
}
li img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%; /* destroys aspect ratio */
}
```

If you have a large screen, the images will fit perfectly. Having smaller devices the images will lose their aspect ratio.

Surely I could use @media(min-width) and change the img from width to height, but due to using BootStrap and having a very dynamic layout (collapsing sidebar, etc) this could become very tricky.

Is there any CSS only solution? If not, is there a great jQuery solution maybe also providing a focus point where to keep the focus on when cropping?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try adding 
`margin:0px`; in `li`'s css
Hope It'll help.

Comment: Try this out, sounds like you might have the same problem I just found a solution for: http://www.sitepoint.com/maintain-image-aspect-ratios-responsive-web-design/ If it is, let me know and I can expand this to a full answer.

Comment: Oh, this was 2014, not 2015 :) Maybe the comment helps someone else, at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to fill entire space with image clipping it, ratio will be preserved but image will be partially hidden. vertical-align and negative margin can be used.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/usD2d/2/ keeping center image in center(like would a `background-position: center center  ;`.

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align:center;/* set image in center */
    line-height:150px;/* set image or text right in middle;*/
}
img {
    min-width: 100%;
    vertical-align:middle;/* okay see it in middle , but you can tune this */
    margin:-50% -100%; /* okay, you can tune margin to crop/clip other area */
}
```

the negative margin reduce virtually size of image wich will center(text-align ) and sit on baseline set by line-height.

This a CSS cropping.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want the image to determine the width of the `<li>`. I removed the `width: 25%;` property, and your images kept their aspect ratio in your fiddle. So change

```
li /* container */ {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
width: 25%;
height: 100px; /* something fixed */
}
```

to

```
li /* container */ {
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
height: 100px; /* something fixed */
}
```